# Error con android.graphics.Paint

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy empezando con Android y su IDE. Estoy siguiendo un manual un poco desactualizado pero que la mayoría de las cosas que describe están vigentes. Entonces con la descripción de este error que me proporciona AndroidStudio no consigo averiguar el por qué del fallo, que estoy seguro es una tontería, pero ando algo perdido.

El tema es que estoy creando dos objetos Paint y cuando quiero modificar alguna de sus propiedades, como el color o el estilo, me dice:

- Que no reconoce el método.
- Y puede que derivado del primer fallo, no reconoce los valores que le paso.

Dejo el código con el que estoy trabajando:

```
    public class ExtendedEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    Paint p1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint p2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);//--------> Aquí da error
    p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);//---> Aquí da error
    p2.setColor(Color.WHITE);//--------> Aquí da error

    public ExtendedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExtendedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExtendedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Saludos y bienvenido a `stackoverflow`, quería pedirte en este caso coloques el error exacto que te muestra el log de `Android Studio`, de esta forma seria mas fácil ayudarte con tu problema.